Can I carbonate at room temperature?
I recently brewed an ESB and this was the first time I keged it, attached to the CO2 and let it sit there for a few weeks. In the past I used to just put it in the keg, attach the CO2, shake the keg a lot and then bottle it.
Online looking at CO2 charts, the highest okay temperature is 65deg. Is it okay to carb at room temperature (70-72)? If so, what should I set the PSI at? I was having a hard time getting the carbonation correct.
Also the night before we were all going to drink it, I put the keg on ice and set the PSI at 15 to try and get it carbed better. The day we were drinking it, I was having to turn the PSI almost to 0 and I was having to let out pressure from the keg in order to keep the glass from being all foam.
I won't have a fridge/chest freezer for the near future, what is the best way to deal with this situation?

The reason that everyone that force-carbonates works with chilled beer is that the solubility of carbon dioxide increases dramatically as the temperature drops. This makes it easier/faster.
I think you have two main options:

Keep doing what you are doing, but work to either find a carbonation chart that covers your temperature range or experiment yourself to find a good combination of pressure and time.
Abandon force carbonation and instead prime (add a measured amount of sugar), seal the keg, and let it carbonate naturally. I do this on a regular basis with very good success. I find that I need about half as much priming sugar in the keg as I would use if I were bottling (a good middle-ground seems to be 1.8oz of dextrose in 5 gallons of beer). I don't know why this is, but I can tell you that it works. Your room temperature will be perfect to support natural carbonation.


just curious. Any thoughts on using sucrose (table sugar) instead of dextrose (corn sugar)?

@HomeBrew Dextrose is 42 points per pound per gallon, while sucrose is 46 points per pound per gallon. So, 1.8oz dextrose would have the same carbonation level as 1.64oz of sucrose.
